# How do I refactor this javascript code to make it shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello**
I am new to new to web development and JavaScript just started few weeks ago, please help me make this code as short as possible. 
How do I refactor this JavaScript code to make it shorter?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.URL.indexOf("movie1") != -1) {
    document.getElementById("aflam-body").style.background = "red";
    document.getElementById('mttitle').innerHTML=document.getElementById('moviz-name-1').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("pr1").style.display = "block";
    var elms = document.querySelectorAll("#movie2, #movie3, #movie4, #movie5, #movie6, #movie7, #movie8, #movie9");

    for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) elms[i].style.display='none';
}
else {} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.URL.indexOf("movie2") != -1) {
    document.getElementById("aflam-body").style.background = "grey";
    document.getElementById('mttitle').innerHTML=document.getElementById('moviz-name-2').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("pr2").style.display = "block";
    var elms = document.querySelectorAll("#movie1, #movie3, #movie4, #movie5, #movie6, #movie7, #movie8, #movie9");

    for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) elms[i].style.display='none';
}
else {} 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function bk1 () {
    d.g("movie1").style.width = "184px";
    d.g("im1").style.height = "50%";
    d.g("im1").style.width = "94%";
    d.g('im1').src='img/aflam3.png'; 
    d.g('movie1').style.background="red url('img/ox-kkk.png')";
    d.g('movie2').style.display = "inline-block";
    d.g('movie3').style.display = "inline-block";
    d.g('movie4').style.display = "inline-block";
    document.querySelector('#moviz-name-1').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go1 () {
    d.g("movie1").style.width = "90%";
    d.g("im1").style.width = "90%";
    d.g("im1").style.height = "60%";
    d.g("movie1").style.backgroundSize = "30%";  
    d.g('movie1').style.background="red url('img/favicon.png')  center"; 
    d.g('movie2').style.display = "none";
    d.g('movie3').style.display = "none";
    d.g('movie4').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('#moviz-name-1').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function bk2 () {
    d.g("movie2").style.width = "184px";
    d.g("im2").style.height = "50%";
    d.g("im2").style.width = "94%";
    d.g('im2').src='img/aflam3.png'; 
    d.g('movie2').style.background="red url('img/ox-kkk.png')";
    d.g('movie1').style.display = "inline-block";
    d.g('movie3').style.display = "inline-block";
    d.g('movie4').style.display = "inline-block";
    document.querySelector('#moviz-name-2').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go2 () {
    d.g("movie2").style.width = "90%";
    d.g("im2").style.width = "90%";
    d.g("im2").style.height = "60%";
    d.g("movie2").style.backgroundSize = "30%";  
    d.g('movie2').style.background="red url('img/favicon.png')  center"; 
    d.g('movie1').style.display = "none";
    d.g('movie3').style.display = "none";
    d.g('movie4').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector('#moviz-name-2').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});}
</script>
```

Comment: at least using class in stead of inline styles would save you some code from code snippet 2.

Comment: Use jquery it has less shorter code than JavaScript

Comment: looking for someone who have few seconds to show me how it should look like, i am new i can't write the short code with my knowledge, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SO shouldn't be used as a "how do I do my homework" website, I think there are a few valuable lessons to be gained, both theoretically and practically.

First, looking at your top code block, you have two sections that look for an object (without an event firing), then select a few objects, perform formatting, then loop through an array of objects. IMO the best way to achieve the same effect would be to leverage jQuery and its [chaining](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) feature. I would look for commonalities between the code blocks to reuse:

```
<!-- In the <head> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- Wherever you want your JS to execute -->
<script>
  // Execute the following block when DOM is ready
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
       if( jQuery("#movie"+i).length ){
         // simple if statement for 2 states; use objects for n > 2
         jQuery("#aflam-body").css("background", i==1?"red":"grey");
         // Leverage the counter variable to grab the matching object
         jQuery('#mttitle').html(jQuery('#moviz-name-'+i).html());
         jQuery("#pr"+i).show();
         jQuery("#movie1, #movie3, #movie4, #movie5, #movie6, #movie7, #movie8, #movie9").hide();
       }
    }
  });
</script>
```

You can obviously get as fancy as you want but the above is much cleaner to read, scalable, and reusable. For the bottom code block, leverage jQuery and chaining:

```
<script>
function bk1 () {
    jQuery("#movie1").css("width", "184px");
    jQuery("#im1").css("height", "50%").css("width", "94%").attr("src", "img/aflam3.png");
    // Enter additional object manipulations here
 }
// Enter additional functions here

</script>
```

Again, there are many ways to skin a cat, but when coding in any language, keep in mind the principles of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3). Good luck!

Comment: i can't include files because it will need to make http requests, this not option for me, i want to make the code short and light.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i learned a lot from your code.

Comment: Sure thing - jQuery is so widely used nowadays there a numerous CDNs hosting it that would make the request go unnoticed...or you could host the file yourself. Finally you could minimize and embed inline but this is not recommended. IMO the benefits outweigh the additional http request.